# Issue getting gettext to work with conditional statements

Tags: conditional-tags

I've been trying to apply a `gettext` filter to return two different results for different product categories (or read as categories for posts, non-woocommerce specific).

I cant seem to get it right. This loads, but does not actually apply the conditional, it always defaults to else condition.  What am I missing?  This is added to my child theme's functions.php.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
            switch ( $translated_text ) {
                        case 'Related Products' :
                                    if  (is_product_category( 'providers' ) ) {
                                        $translated_text = __( 'Check out these other Providers', 'woocommerce' );
                                        } else {
                                        $translated_text = __( 'Check out reviews of other Providers', 'woocommerce' );
                                        }
                                        break;
                                        }
            return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had success with the following where I specifically set the $domain. In your instance you might want to change $domain to $woocommerce. Take a look at the original related_products function and see how it is outputted using the localisation function to determine what domain to use.

Hope that helps

```
    function wpa_translate_email( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){
        if( $domain == 'woothemes' && $translated_text == 'E-mail' && is_front_page() )
            $translated_text = 'Enter your email for news, recipes and offers';

        return $translated_text;
    }

    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpa_translate_email', 10, 3 );
```